# Not able to handle browser pop-up in Selenium using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to automate a website where in i am stuck with the first step which is i have to handle a pop-up which accepts username, password.
If the pop-up displays soon after i launch the site i could have handled it using
`driver.get("http:username :password@example.com)`
But my problem is that authentication pop-up is not getting displayed as soon as I launch the browser because of which I'm getting the error with the above code.

I have click on the sign in button and then the authentication pop-up shows up, I'm able to click on the sign in button but I'm not able to send username and password to the pup up

I tried using Alert class and still not able to handle.

I am not able to inspect the pop-up as well

Please suggest me any solution, i am using **Jave Selenium **

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you're dealing with a basic authentication pop-up (HTTP Basic Authentication), you won't be able to interact with it using Selenium directly because it's a browser-level authentication prompt, not a part of the web page DOM. However, you can still handle it by providing the username and password directly in the URL.

Since you mentioned that the pop-up doesn't appear immediately and only after clicking the sign-in button, you'll need to handle the click first and then navigate to the URL with the credentials. Here's a step-by-step approach:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class HandleAuthenticationPopup {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Set the path to the ChromeDriver executable
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path_to_chromedriver");

        // Initialize ChromeDriver
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        // Maximize the browser window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        // Navigate to the website
        driver.get("https://example.com");

        // Locate and click the sign-in button
        WebElement signInButton = driver.findElement(By.id("sign-in-button"));
        signInButton.click();

        // Wait for the authentication pop-up to appear (you may need to add an explicit wait here)

        // Provide username and password in the URL
        String username = "your_username";
        String password = "your_password";
        String urlWithCredentials = "http://" + username + ":" + password + "@example.com";

        // Navigate to the URL with credentials
        driver.get(urlWithCredentials);

        // Now you should be logged in and able to interact with the authenticated content
    }
}
```

Replace "path_to_chromedriver", "https://example.com", "your_username", and "your_password" with the appropriate values for your environment and website.

This approach should bypass the authentication pop-up by directly providing the credentials in the URL after clicking the sign-in button. Make sure to handle any synchronization issues or explicit waits as needed to ensure the sign-in button click triggers the appearance of the pop-up.

Comment: I am still getting the error-  SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Feb 09, 2024 8:45:54 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 121, so returning the closest version found: 117
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
  (Session info: chrome=121.0.6167.160)